# Find the word that connects these words

Tags: word

Under water

Hair ties

Wood work

Short let

---

**Question** What single word connects these pairs of words?

Comment: Is it [tag:lateral-thinking]?

Comment: Is it the same word for all pairs, or does each pair has its own connecting word ?

Comment: Bjorn Eriksson - It is the same word throughout

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This word may make the

> **cut**
>
>  undercut
>  cutwater - the curved forward stem of a ship
>  haircut
>  [cutties](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cuttie#English) - e.g. surfing maneuvers or hares
>  woodcut -an engraved block of wood
>  cutwork - a form of embroidery
>  shortcut
>  cutlet

Answer (score 4):

If the connecting words are all different, then these are my guesses.

> Under **ground** water - Underground, groundwater.
>
>  Hair **bow** ties - Hairbow, bowties
>
>  Wood **needle** work - Woodneedle, needlework
>
>  Short **out** let - Shortout, outlet